# Facebook won't let me access my account

Tags: facebook

I have tried answering the security questions and I am being blocked from accessing my account.  I do not have a mobile phone so cannot have a code sent to me by text to access my Facebook account. I will not scan any government ID as that seems extreme to me and not secure in order to identify myself.

Can I get the code by email?

Comment: Have you tried our search? This is a common topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you see the help center of Facebook ? [Help for log-in](http://www.facebook.com/help/www/374104332645037?rdrhc)

(sorry not any rep to put this as comment so i reply as answer)